# Alignment symbols with super-scripts

Tags: alignment, superscripts

Consider the MWE

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  A_{X}, A_{X_{1}}, A_{X_{b}^{2}}, A_{\bar X_{b}^{2}},
  A_{\overline X_{b}^{2}}
\]
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Adding subscripts (or even underlines) does not affect the alignment of X. But adding superscripts, bars or overlines causes the X to be pushed down.

Is there a way to fix this? I would rather stack the superscripts above X just like the subscripts are stacked under, without moving X. In some cases, I can use `vphantom` to align everything, but I am looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant part of appendix G of the texbook is

> The idea is
> to make sure that the subscript is shifted by at least~$v$ and by at
> least $\sigma_{16}$; furthermore, the top of the subscript should not extend
> above $4\over5$~of the current x-height.

Without adding `\smash` or similar in the expression you can't control the height of the subscript or the x height, so the only paramenter you can control is 16 which is the default drop:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\centering

default (1.5pt)
\[
  A_{X}, A_{X_{1}}, A_{X_{b}^{2}}, A_{\bar X_{b}^{2}},
  A_{\overline X_{b}^{2}}
\]


adjusted 2pt
\fontdimen16\textfont2=2pt
\[
  A_{X}, A_{X_{1}}, A_{X_{b}^{2}}, A_{\bar X_{b}^{2}},
  A_{\overline X_{b}^{2}}
\]


adjusted 3pt
\fontdimen16\textfont2=3pt
\[
  A_{X}, A_{X_{1}}, A_{X_{b}^{2}}, A_{\bar X_{b}^{2}},
  A_{\overline X_{b}^{2}}
\]

adjusted 4pt
\fontdimen16\textfont2=4pt
\[
  A_{X}, A_{X_{1}}, A_{X_{b}^{2}}, A_{\bar X_{b}^{2}},
  A_{\overline X_{b}^{2}}
\]
\end{document}
```